Help with Variational Problem involving Transversality Conditions
I am encountering some issues in trying to find extremals to the functional
$$J(y)=\int_0^ag(x, y, y')dx=\int_0^a(y^2+y'^2)dx,$$ given that $y(0)=0$ and $y(a)$ ($a$ is unknown) lies on the line $y=1-x$.
From the Euler-Lagrange equation I got a general solution in the form $$y=c_1\sinh(x+c_2),$$ which I simplified to $$y=c_1\sinh(x)$$ using the first boundary condition. To solve for the second constant and the upper bound, I used the transversality condition that, assuming the line is parameterized in terms of $t$, $$\frac{dy}{dt}\frac{\partial g}{\partial y'}-\frac{dx}{dt}\left(y'\frac{\partial g}{\partial y'}-g\right)=0,$$ with the terms with $g$ evaluated at  $x=a$. This yielded the equation $$\frac{-c_1^2}{2} = \cosh(a),$$ which has no solution. Playing with negative roots and negative constants yields similar equations that don't seem to have any solutions. The way my book words question makes it seem as though there is in fact a solution, and I wanted to see if anybody else could find a different solution, using the tranversality conditions.

Why don't you use the boundary condition $y(a)=1-a$? It implies $c_1\sinh(a)=1-a$, hence $c_1=(1-a)/\sinh(a)$.

How does that help solve the problem, since $a$ is unknown?

Compute $f(a):=J[(1-a)\sinh(x)/\sinh(a)]$, then find the extremals of $f(a)$.

I can see that approach now. However, my book intends for it to specifically be solved with the transversality conditions. Is there no way of achieving the same result with the transversality conditions?


Since OP's integration region $[0,a]$ is not fixed, we can strictly speaking not assume the Euler-Lagrange (EL) equation before analyzing OP's system further.

If we use a Lagrange multiplier, OP's extended functional reads:
$$\begin{align} \widetilde{J}[y;\lambda,a]
~:=~&J[y;a]+ \lambda(1-a-y(a))\cr
J[y;a]~:=~&\int_0^a\!dx~g(x) , \cr g(x)~:=~&y^{\prime 2}+y^2. \end{align}\tag{A}$$

An infinitesimal variation is
$$\begin{align} \delta\widetilde{J}[y;\lambda,a]~:=~&\int_0^a\!dx~\underbrace{e(x)}_{=0}\delta y+ \underbrace{\{p(a)-\lambda\}}_{=0}\delta y(a) - p(0)\underbrace{\delta y(0)}_{=0} \cr
&+\underbrace{\{L(a)-\lambda(1+y^{\prime}(a))\}}_{=0}\delta a +\underbrace{\{1-a-y(a)\}}_{=0}\delta\lambda
, \cr 
e(x)~:=~&\frac{\delta J}{\delta y}~=~-2y^{\prime\prime}+2y\cr 
p(x)~:=~&\frac{\partial g}{\partial y^{\prime}}~=~2y^{\prime}. \end{align}\tag{B}$$

Now let us analyze necessary conditions for a stationary configuration
$$ \delta\widetilde{J}[y;\lambda,a]~=~0.\tag{C}$$
OP assumes an initial condition. Arbitrary infinitesimal variations $\delta y$, $\delta y(a)$, $\delta a$, $\delta\lambda$ lead to the EL eq. plus 3 other stationary conditions as indicated in eq. (B).

Two of the stationary conditions (the EL eq. plus the initial condition) leads to
$$ y(x)~=~A\sinh x, \qquad A~\in~\mathbb{R}. \tag{D}$$
Therefore the other 3 stationary conditions (presumably  transversality conditions in OP's terminology) become transcendental equations
$$\begin{align}
 2A\cosh a~=~&\lambda, \cr
 A^2(\cosh^2a+\sinh^2a)~=~&\lambda(1+A\cosh a), \cr
1-a~=~&A\sinh a,
\end{align}\tag{E}$$
which has the exact solution
$$ a~=~1,\qquad A~=~0,\qquad \lambda~=~0,\tag{F} $$
and the approximate numerical solution
$$ a~\approx~-0.633,\qquad A~\approx~-2.415,\qquad \lambda~\approx~-5.830.\tag{G} $$


